# how to find group words with similar substrings?

Tags: r, text

what are the simple methods to find words with similar substrings (at least 3 characters) from a vector of words?

```
words <- c("fanboy","fangirl","fanbase","fantastic","fancy", "waddle","goodwill","goodbye","goodies")
```

For example, how can i get the a group of five 5 words from here as they all contain "fan" substring, and a group of last 3 words as they all contain "good" substring?

Comment: do you mean grep? `like words[grep(x = words, pattern = "fan")]`

Comment: You can see what's going on with something like `heatmap(as.matrix(stringdist::stringdistmatrix(words, method = 'qgram', q = 2, useNames = TRUE)))`, though this may be a better question for [CrossValidated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/) if you're trying to find an appropriate algorithm.